# Change Minimum ROAS Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-ads

I am using the Facebook Ads API (Graph API) to change bid amounts, campaign names and more. However, I am now adopting the minimum ROAS strategy for some campaigns and I don't know how to insert or change this value via API.

I expected the minimum ROAS field to be similar to the Bid Amount field, as the minimum ROAS replaces the bid amount when changing manually on the platform.

Keen to know if anyone has found a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum roas field is placed under the "Bid Constraints" field, so that's the place you should be looking for to update it.